# Change Data Capture (CDC) Performance issues

Tags: sql-server, ssis, cdc

I am using CDC in SQL Server 2008 and triggering it via SSIS(In the form Stored procedures and calling commands like table-diff in EST). Recently i came across a different issue and I am simply not understanding what might be the reason. What exactly happened is CDC suddenly hanged while executing. It was in running state for almost around two days. After that we manually had to kill CDC process in order to run the next batch for the same. When I ran same CDC job next time it ran properly without any interruption (Completed in few minutes/No changes were made to package or anywhere before next execution).When that process was executing for around two days I checked changed records, except for 2-3 new Inserts/Updates nothing was there. After going through log file details I came to know my table-diff cmd took around 5 hours to execute which normally takes around 5 mins for my package everyday.I just want to know what might be the possible reason for such behaviour.

PS: Such behaviour occurred few times in past as well.

Comment: Do you have a large DML operation that the log reader is having to process? Check sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions. And when you say that CDC hung, do you mean the log reader or the processing of CDC records? If the latter, it could be that when you restart, that the large amount of records is aging out of your retention period and so you're ultimately not processing them.

Comment: @BenThul Thank You for your reply Sir.No there are no large DML operations.Checked sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions it is not giving any records or information.Even I checked the trace file(.trc) on what all processes which ran on that day,still wasn't able to detect the actual issue.Actually we have implemented it in a 3 step process. Step 1 got hanged which creates CHLOG tables(table gets created using table-diff cmd) and Insert's I/U/D  operations audit information  in __CT tables.

Comment: @BenThul Now as per of your comment lets just say when I restart my batch,  large amount of records is aging out of retention period ,so in order to avoid such things in future what should be the steps which you would suggest.

Comment: If it's crucial that you consume all of the CDC data, you'll need to set your retention period sufficiently high that you can deal with any intermittent failures in your ETL process. You can do this with `sys.sp_cdc_change_job`.

Comment: Also, why are you running table-diff? CDC is able to take two endpoints (internally LSN values but you can translate time to LSN with some fidelity) and return you all of the activity that happened between the two.